# Sun/moon dial on a watch

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the name for the dial on a wristwatch or clock which rotates to display a sun symbol at midday and a moon symbol or or night scene at midnight?

Comment: 'I doubt very much that there's a dedicated name for that particular "dial". It's usually just called a [Sun and Moon indicator](http://yeomanseiko.com/2012/08/09/orient-sun-moon-etop003w/)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Actually, I wouldn't have been surprised at all to find there was a specific name for that piece – but an obscure word, and more likely answered on Clockmakers.SE than on English.SE. :^) Still, I found it interesting to learn that some clocks have sun-and-moon dials to indicate the time of day, but others have [moon dials](http://www.masterclockrepair.com/howtosetamoondial.html), to indicate the phase of the moon.

Comment: Any thing but avoid *sundial* & *moondial* because they are commonly understood to mean entirely different things. *sundial*: 'An instrument showing the time by the shadow of a pointer cast by the sun onto a plate marked with the hours of the day.' *moondial*: 'a dial used to indicate time by moonlight.'

Comment: @Kris: I agree about avoiding _sundial_, but I think _sun dial_ and _sundial_ are not the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Antiquorum-Lexico.pdf](http://www.nawcc-index.net/Articles/Antiquorum-Lexico.pdf), an  “Illustrated Horological
Glossary”, on page 134 (pdf page 13) apparently refers to that dial like that as a “Day/night” dial.

Astronomically-related terms elsewhere in the glossary's dial section include  *Astrolabe*, p. 133;  *Moon phase* and *Planetarium*, p. 136;  *Star chart* and  *Sunrise, sunset*, p. 137.

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia :
An [astronomical clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_clock) is a clock with special mechanisms and dials to display astronomical information, such as the relative positions of the sun, moon, zodiacal constellations, and sometimes major planets.

So, I gess, you could call that an astronomical wristwatch or dial, as they do in the article.

Comment: except that it's just a half-speed version of the hour hand (like a 24-hour watch), rather than knowing about the positions of planets or phase of moon (but upvote because interesting link!).